# Which of these is preferable? Adding a column to the table or using sub-query to get data?

Tags: sql, performance, subquery

What I meant was, there's a Table A having 5 columns. I have a SP that I use to get 3 columns from Table A and one column from Table B. Now, would it be better to add the column from Table B to Table A or use a sub-query in that SP to get that column from Table B?

Comment: What are you talking about? A subquery is a query within a query. How could adding a subquery inside a stored procedure and adding a column in a table do the same thing??? Please clarify what you are doing. Show table structures and code and tell us what you want to achieve.

Comment: You also need to tell us which DBMS you are using. Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: The question itself is a confusing question.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2. 
What I meant was, there's a Table A having 5 columns. I have a SP that I use to get 3 columns from Table A and one column from Table B. Now, would it be better to add the column from Table B to Table A or use a sub-query in that SP to get that column from Table B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is still confusing and it very much looks like you haven't understood how to use a relational database. So let me try to explain:

Let's say you have two tables:

**client**

```
client_number
first_name
last_name
date_of_birth
...
```

**order**

```
order_number
client_number
order_date
...
```

These are two separate tables, so as to have a normalized relational database. The order table contains the client number, so you can look up the clients name and date of birth in the client table. The date of birth may be important in order know whether the client is allowed to order certain articles. But you don't want to store the date of birth with every order - it doesn't change.

If you want to look up the age you *can* use a **sub query**:

```
select
  order_number,
  order_date,
  quantity,
  (
    select date_of_birth 
    from client c
    where c.client_number = o.client_number
  )
from order o
where item = 'whisky';
```

but most often you would simply *join* the tables:

```
select
  o.order_number,
  o.order_date,
  o.quantity,
  c.date_of_birth,
  c.first_name,
  c.last_name  
from order o
join client c on c.client_number = o.client_number;
```

You would however *not* change your tables and invite redundancy with all its problems only not to have to join. You design your database such that it is a well-formed relational database, not such that it makes your latest query easy to write. It is very, very common to use joins and subqueries, and having to use them usually shows that you built your database well.

I think this a good time you look up **database normalization**, e.g. in Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization.

Comment: Thanks. That's the answer I was looking for. You explained it properly.